# how to load posts to a custom post template after using template_redirect or template_include

Tags: wp-query, urls, globals, parameter, template-redirect

I need to use the URL parameter **?m=1** to load every page of my wordpress with a different template but the problem is that I can't pull the text and posts that can be accessed using the canonical URL
I tried different methods the best one that worked for me is using **template_redirect** action hook or **template_include** filter
the problem is that I can't load data to the template file using any of this method the template load but the page is blank and with some methods it returns 404 error
to better explain my problem

I added this code to the end of **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_template' );

function custom_template($template) {
   global $post, $wp_query;
  if ($wp_query->query_vars['m'] === '1') {
    return TEMPLATEPATH . '/custom-template.php';
  } else {
    return $template;
  }
}
```

I can't load the posts to the template file **custom-template.php** with this code it returns blank

```
<div id="content">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <h2 class="item"><span class="fn"><?php the_title(); ?></span></h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

the code render blank

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I need to have a custom template with the URL parameter **?m=1** and load the same post in the canonical URL
is there any working method to show custom template with valid post data and headers using the url parameter **?m=1**

Comment: Try with something more unique than `m`, that's already a WordPress query var.

Comment: I know that m is a reserved wordpress query but I'm looking for a workaround as I need to show posts with the same query

Comment: I'm not sure I understand- why can't you change `m` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the full code to force change theme by a reserved wordpress parameter

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    'my_pre_get_posts'
);

function my_pre_get_posts($wp_query) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Confirm request is main query
    if(!$wp_query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    // Get post name from query
    $post_name = $wp_query->get('pagename');

    // Get post type from database
    $post_type = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            'SELECT post_type FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_name = %s LIMIT 1',
            $post_name
        )
    );

    // Confirm page is post
    if ($post_type === 'post') {
        $wp_query->set('m', '');
    }
}

add_action(
    'template_redirect',
    'my_template_redirect'
);

function my_template_redirect() {
    global $post, $wp_query;

    if ($wp_query->query['m'] === '123') {
        include TEMPLATEPATH . '/template-name.php';
        die();
    }
}
```

you can also use the template include method instead of template_redirect hook as long as you add global $wp_query to your function